# Flutter: How to get buttons side by side instead of one below the other?

Tags: flutter, dart, button

I currently have the following widget and I need to add a new button to it. However, the buttons show up one below the other instead of side by side. I tried to use Row instead of Column as well & that messed up the entire page. Any ideas on how to get these buttons side by side? Thank you!!

```
 Widget getRequestAmount() {
return AppTextField(
  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30),
  focusNode: _transferAmountNode,
  controller: _transferAmountController,
  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
  hintText: 'Request Amount',
 
  inputFormatters: [
    /*  CurrencyFormatter(
                        currency: _selectedAccount?.currency ?? '') */
  ],
  onSubmitted: (value) {
    setState(() {
      this.showQR = true;
    });
    Navigator.pop(context);
    Sheets.showAppHeightEightSheet(
        context: context,
        widget: Column(children: <Widget>[
          getBuyerAvatar(),
          showAmount(),
          _contentWidget(),
          Container(margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5, bottom: 5)),
          AppButton.buildAppButton(
              context,
              AppButtonType.TEXT_OUTLINE,
              'Button 1',
              Dimens.BUTTON_BOTTOM_DIMENS, onPressed: () async {
            Uint8List generateImgFromQR = await _captureAndCreateQRPng();
            Sheets.showAppHeightEightSheet(
              context: context,
              widget: generatePDF(generateImgFromQR),
            );
          }),
          AppButton.buildAppButton(
              context,
              AppButtonType.TEXT_OUTLINE,
              'Second Button',
              Dimens.BUTTON_BOTTOM_DIMENS, onPressed: () async {
            moneyAmount = _transferAmountController.text;
            Sheets.showAppHeightEightSheet(
              context: context,
              widget: generatePDF(generateImgFromQR),
            );
          })

        ]));
  },
);
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wrap only two buttons in a row Widget

```
Widget getRequestAmount() {
return AppTextField(
  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30),
  focusNode: _transferAmountNode,
  controller: _transferAmountController,
  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
  hintText: 'Request Amount',
 
  inputFormatters: [
    /*  CurrencyFormatter(
                        currency: _selectedAccount?.currency ?? '') */
  ],
  onSubmitted: (value) {
    setState(() {
      this.showQR = true;
    });
    Navigator.pop(context);
    Sheets.showAppHeightEightSheet(
        context: context,
        widget: Column(children: <Widget>[
          getBuyerAvatar(),
          showAmount(),
          _contentWidget(),
          Container(margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5, bottom: 5)),
          Row(
             children: <Widget>[
              AppButton.buildAppButton(
              context,
              AppButtonType.TEXT_OUTLINE,
              'Button 1',
              Dimens.BUTTON_BOTTOM_DIMENS, onPressed: () async {
            Uint8List generateImgFromQR = await _captureAndCreateQRPng();
            Sheets.showAppHeightEightSheet(
              context: context,
              widget: generatePDF(generateImgFromQR),
            );
          }),
          AppButton.buildAppButton(
              context,
              AppButtonType.TEXT_OUTLINE,
              'Second Button',
              Dimens.BUTTON_BOTTOM_DIMENS, onPressed: () async {
            moneyAmount = _transferAmountController.text;
            Sheets.showAppHeightEightSheet(
              context: context,
              widget: generatePDF(generateImgFromQR),
            );
          })
         ])
        ]));
  },
);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For this you can use the `Row` widget. Which works exactly like the `Column` Widget, which you already use, but it is oriented horizontal.

[You can read more about this widget here.](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Row-class.html)

Your code would then look like:

```
Widget getRequestAmount() {
    return AppTextField(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30),
      focusNode: _transferAmountNode,
      controller: _transferAmountController,
      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
      hintText: 'Request Amount',
      inputFormatters: [
        /*  CurrencyFormatter(
                        currency: _selectedAccount?.currency ?? '') */
      ],
      onSubmitted: (value) {
        setState(() {
          this.showQR = true;
        });
        Navigator.pop(context);
        Sheets.showAppHeightEightSheet(
          context: context,
          widget: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              getBuyerAvatar(),
              showAmount(),
              _contentWidget(),
              Container(margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5, bottom: 5)),
              Row(
                children: [
                  AppButton.buildAppButton(
                      context,
                      AppButtonType.TEXT_OUTLINE,
                      'Button 1',
                      Dimens.BUTTON_BOTTOM_DIMENS, onPressed: () async {
                    Uint8List generateImgFromQR =
                        await _captureAndCreateQRPng();
                    Sheets.showAppHeightEightSheet(
                      context: context,
                      widget: generatePDF(generateImgFromQR),
                    );
                  }),
                  AppButton.buildAppButton(
                      context,
                      AppButtonType.TEXT_OUTLINE,
                      'Second Button',
                      Dimens.BUTTON_BOTTOM_DIMENS, onPressed: () async {
                    moneyAmount = _transferAmountController.text;
                    Sheets.showAppHeightEightSheet(
                      context: context,
                      widget: generatePDF(generateImgFromQR),
                    );
                  })
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```